# 'No better than they ought to be'?

Tags: ethics

What moral judgement is involved in the claim, less common than it once was but still heard, that 'S/he is no better than s/he ought to be' ? This is a conceptual question, not one about English usage. The claim does not appear to reflect any specific ethical theory - Platonic, Aristotelian, Utilitarian, Intuitionist or other. Nor on the surface does it make sense - the judgement, whatever it may mean, is critical : yet why should one be *better* than one *ought* to be ? If irony is at work, what is the relevant opposite meaning that the judgement carries ?

Comment: Isn't this just a reference to meeting minimal expectations only with a not so veiled sense of one's own superiority, "*“no better than she ought to be, considering her status”.  The assumption being that working class people had lower moral standards than middle or upper class people*", according to [What does no better than she ought to be mean?](http://www.whatdoesthatmean.com/no-better-than-she-ought-to-be/) Arrogance and self-righteousness aside, this simply seems to refer to some hierarchy of oughts, which most moral positions accommodate.

Comment: @Conifold. Thank you, I hadn't thought of that rider - 'considering her status'. It sounds *right*. I'll leave the question open just in case there are possibilities, maybe extra angles that complement or supplement yours. Best - GT

Comment: While it could refer to social class (different people are taught different morals as they grow up, and morality is learned not inborn), I see it as an extreme example of physical and mental limits: non-human animals and people with mental illness may not have the mental capacity for morality, so you really can't blame them for what we consider moral failings.

Comment: @barrycarter. That's one line of approach, certainly, and it hadn't occurred to me. I appreciate.

Comment: I've always taken it to mean the  subject shows no inclination towards self improvement. It is critical on the basis of the predisposition: "one ought to better oneself"

Comment: christo183. Definitely something to think about here. It hadn't occurred to me that opposite expressions might be relevant. Thank you. Best - Geoffrey